# How to get ID from formValues on jFormer onSubmit function

Tags: php, symfony1, jformer

I'm using jFormer to create a form. I have the function below:

```
function onSubmit($formValues) 
{
return array
(
    'successPageHtml' => 'Registro salvo com sucesso!',
    'redirect' => '/kwadmin_dev.php/admin/noticiascadastros/editar/'.$formValues->getId(),
);
```

}

I want to redirect the user to the Id generated on this page. I don't know how to do it.

Someone can help me?